# Map backspace to remove search highlight, and normal action when there is no highligted search in vim

Tags: search, vim, highlight

I normally do this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <backspace> :noh<CR>
```

to remap the backspace button to remove the highlighting from a search, however I would like it so the default action of the backspace button is performed if there is no highligted search. How do I perform this?

Comment: The default action of backspace is the same as h and back arrow. What is the use case in which that would be useful?

Comment: @isaacsloan It's in fact not the same as h, the difference is that backspace will go to the end of the last line if pressed on the first character of the line. As for the back arrow it's very far away, and I've also disabled it to stop a habit of using it.

Comment: Good point. I've never tried using backspace for that as I always just use 'b' for that case. I there any reason that backspace makes more sense than 'b'?

Comment: @isaacsloan Well, I've always used backspace for that. I don't think I ever thought about using b there. Never the less I would like to know if this question is possible to perform

Comment: Why not a different mapping? One common mapping for clearing the highlighting is `:nnoremap <c-l> :noh<cr><c-l>`. If you are using gvim you can clear it with `<esc>` which has a nice feel to it. e.g. `nnoremap <esc> :noh<cr><esc>`

Comment: @PeterRincker I'll use that mapping if the backspace mapping is not possible.

Comment: I'm convinced that everything in vim is possible however I really do think that using either a different mapping as @PeterRincker suggested or just using default vim navigation (wbWBe) or a combination of both would be less of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine if search highlight is currently on by variable `v:hlsearch`, thus, with a `<expr>` mapping, your goal can be achieved. Try this mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> <BS> v:hlsearch?':noh<cr>':'<BS>'
```

Comment: Undefined variable: v:hlsearch

Comment: which vim version do you use? `:h v:hlsearch` for details. @KristofferRyhl

Comment: [output of vim --version](http://pastebin.com/KFXCN8U8), as for `:h v:hlsearch` it gives `Sorry, no help for v:hlsearch`

Comment: @KristofferRyhl the variable is available on version 7.4. Time to upgrade?

Comment: It works now, seems that vim version 7.4 is needed for this feature

Comment: Note: You also need to check the `&hls` option value, otherwise the `v:hlsearch` may not show the right value